# how do you prevent dead rows from hanging around in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have production and staging RDS instances on amazon, and staging's data is a direct copy of production so both instances have duplicate data.

Doing a `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * from my_table WHERE my_col=true;`resulted in this:

```
Seq Scan on my_table (cost=0.00..142,775.73 rows=1 width=1,436) (actual time=18,170.294..18,170.294 rows=0 loops=1) Filter: my_col Rows Removed by Filter: 360275
```

Where as in production, it was:

```
Seq Scan on my_table (cost=0.00..62,145.88 rows=1 width=1,450) (actual time=282.487..282.487 rows=0 loops=1) Filter: my_col Rows Removed by Filter: 366442
```

When running `select pg_total_relation_size('my_table'::regclass);`

I found that staging's size was almost double of production.  From what I've read, I see that postgresql's MVCC is responsible for this as it keeps multiple versions of rows around.  I manually ran `VACUUM FULL` and afterwards saw that staging's size had been cut down by 2/3.  Running that same explain analyze now shows:

```
Seq Scan on my_table  (cost=0.00..56094.75 rows=1 width=1436) (actual time=1987.340..1987.340 rows=0 loops=1) Filter: my_col Rows Removed by Filter: 360287 Total runtime: 1987.547 ms
```

Which is great-- but what I don't understand is, the documentation suggests that auto vacuum should kick in and be cleaning up these dead rows, yet clearly that was not happening.

I've read several places talk about "don't let your indexes get bloat", and I don't quite understand 1) how an index gets bloat, and 2) how to prevent an index from getting bloat.

How can I prevent this from happening again in the future?

**UPDATE**

Here are my autovacuum settings:

```
                name                 |  setting  | unit |  category  |                                        short_desc                                         | extra_desc |  context   | vartype | source  |  min_val  |  max_val   | enumvals | boot_val  | reset_val | sourcefile | sourceline
-------------------------------------+-----------+------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------
 autovacuum                          | on        |      | Autovacuum | Starts the autovacuum subprocess.                                                         |            | sighup     | bool    | default |           |            |          | on        | on        |            |
 autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor     | 0.1       |      | Autovacuum | Number of tuple inserts, updates, or deletes prior to analyze as a fraction of reltuples. |            | sighup     | real    | default | 0         | 100        |          | 0.1       | 0.1       |            |
 autovacuum_analyze_threshold        | 50        |      | Autovacuum | Minimum number of tuple inserts, updates, or deletes prior to analyze.                    |            | sighup     | integer | default | 0         | 2147483647 |          | 50        | 50        |            |
 autovacuum_freeze_max_age           | 200000000 |      | Autovacuum | Age at which to autovacuum a table to prevent transaction ID wraparound.                  |            | postmaster | integer | default | 100000000 | 2000000000 |          | 200000000 | 200000000 |            |
 autovacuum_max_workers              | 3         |      | Autovacuum | Sets the maximum number of simultaneously running autovacuum worker processes.            |            | postmaster | integer | default | 1         | 8388607    |          | 3         | 3         |            |
 autovacuum_multixact_freeze_max_age | 400000000 |      | Autovacuum | Multixact age at which to autovacuum a table to prevent multixact wraparound.             |            | postmaster | integer | default | 10000000  | 2000000000 |          | 400000000 | 400000000 |            |
 autovacuum_naptime                  | 60        | s    | Autovacuum | Time to sleep between autovacuum runs.                                                    |            | sighup     | integer | default | 1         | 2147483    |          | 60        | 60        |            |
 autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay        | 20        | ms   | Autovacuum | Vacuum cost delay in milliseconds, for autovacuum.                                        |            | sighup     | integer | default | -1        | 100        |          | 20        | 20        |            |
 autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit        | -1        |      | Autovacuum | Vacuum cost amount available before napping, for autovacuum.                              |            | sighup     | integer | default | -1        | 10000      |          | -1        | -1        |            |
 autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor      | 0.2       |      | Autovacuum | Number of tuple updates or deletes prior to vacuum as a fraction of reltuples.            |            | sighup     | real    | default | 0         | 100        |          | 0.2       | 0.2       |            |
 autovacuum_vacuum_threshold         | 50        |      | Autovacuum | Minimum number of tuple updates or deletes prior to vacuum.                               |            | sighup     | integer | default | 0         | 2147483647 |          | 50        | 50        |            |
```

Comment: Could you show us the configuration for auto vacuum? And do you use a specific auto vacuum configuration for this table?

Comment: I updated my question with the output of select * from pg_settings where name like 'autovacuum%';

Comment: Best settings depend on your typical write and read patterns. Probably helpful: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/37028/3684, http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/18664/3684

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Auto-vacuuming should eventually get around to cleaning it up (assuming you haven't disabled it), but it may not be getting around to it soon enough for your purposes. There are many settings which can control auto-vacuuming and how/when it's done, which may be of interest: [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html#AUTOVACUUM) and [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-autovacuum.html).

This can be especially true of tables with high churn. That is, tables with lots of insertions and deletions. Long-running and idle transactions can also be a factor here, as *MVCC* will kick in and prevent the dead tuples from being reclaimed. The fact that manually doing a `VACUUM` frees the dead tuples suggests that this isn't the case for you, though, and it may be the former issue instead.

In general, it's not recommended to do a `VACUUM FULL`, as that takes out an exclusive table lock, particularly when most rows in a table have been updated/deleted.

From the [doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-vacuum.html):

> The FULL option is not recommended for routine use, but might be
>   useful in special cases. An example is when you have deleted or
>   updated most of the rows in a table and would like the table to
>   physically shrink to occupy less disk space and allow faster table
>   scans. VACUUM FULL will usually shrink the table more than a plain
>   VACUUM would.

Is your usage pattern such that this would be the case? You did mention a "direct copy" was involved, but it's not clear exactly how that's being done.

I have had cases with high-churn tables where the default auto-vacuum rate just wasn't enough, and even relatively small amounts of dead tuples would greatly affect the query speed (this was in a large table which was queried very often and where the query needed to be extremely fast, and as such, was highly affected by dead tuples).

To help with this, I setup a manual `VACUUM ANALYZE` of the table (so it will both free up the tuples and aid the query planner by updating the stats) in a cron job that was set to run every 5 minutes. Since there weren't that many dead tuples, the `VACUUM` was pretty fast, and the constant vacuuming keeps the dead tuple count low enough so as to keep queries of that table fast.

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

In the [VACUUM doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-vacuum.html), it says that:

> VACUUM reclaims storage occupied by dead tuples

The doc then says that (emphasis mine):

> **VACUUM ANALYZE performs a VACUUM and then an ANALYZE for each selected
>   table**. This is a handy combination form for routine maintenance
>   scripts. See ANALYZE for more details about its processing.

So it definitely reclaims dead tuples.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.  This table has hundreds of thousands of rows, and is indexed via elasticsearch, so there is a flag that gets set when we need to tell elasticsearch to reindex records.  When there are major changes, we have to do that to the entire table-- it's simply flipping a boolean column from false to true, but apparently this is really bad as it's creating gazillions of dead rows.  That's why I used vacuum full.  Can you tell me where it says that vacuum analyze removes dead rows?  The docs I read said that it only updates statistics for the planner, not free up tuples?

Comment: Sure, no problem. It should definitely reclaim dead tuples. I added more details to my answer above.

Answer (score 3):

***the documentation suggests that auto vacuum should kick in and be cleaning up these dead rows, yet clearly that was not happening.***

To know if autovacuum processes a table, look at `pg_catalog.pg_stat_user_tables.last_autovacuum`.

You seem to believe that autovacuum doesn't run because a manual `VACUUM FULL` shrinks the table and autovacuum doesn't. But that's normal, as autovacuum is not supposed to shrink tables, it only flags the space occupied by dead rows as reusable.

***1) how an index gets bloat, and 2) how to prevent an index from getting bloat.***

Index bloat happens as soon as writes happen, it cannot be prevented. What needs to be checked is if the bloat grows indefinitely or stays stable and how bad it is.

The postgres wiki provides a query for that:
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Show_database_bloat