# Can I do VACUUM FULL to pg_largeobject table?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, blob

I have two tables (`table1`, `table2`) in a Postgres 9.1 database. Both having oid type. Each table 1 million records. And `pg_largeobject` table size is around 40GB. I have removed 0.9 million records from each table, and executed the below command.

```
vacuum full analyze table1;
vacuum full analyze table2;
```

Still no change in `pg_largeobject` table size (auto vacuum is enabled)

Do I need to execute above command to `pg_largeobject` table too? Will it impact anything?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You *can* run that, no problem:

```
VACUUM FULL ANALYZE pg_largeobject;
```

Might even remove some dead rows. Details:

- [VACUUM returning disk space to operating system](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37028/vacuum-returning-disk-space-to-operating-system/37032#37032)

But it's probably ***not*** going to solve your ***actual problem***.

When using the [***large object*** facility of Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/largeobjects.html), large objects ("blob": binary large object) themselves are broken up in chuncks of binary data stored in the system table `pg_largeobject`. The PK consists of two columns `(loid, pageno)`, `loid` is the `oid` that is used to refer to the blob in user table(s). The same blob *can* be referenced by OID many times.

Deleting rows in user tables does *not* remove the blob. For one, the same blob might be referenced more than one times. It is your responsibility to keep track and actually delete "unlinked" blobs yourself. One way would be to use [`lo_unlink()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/lo-funcs.html):

```
SELECT lo_unlink(173454);  -- deletes large object with OID 173454
```

Since you already deleted rows with the `oid` reference, you need to be a bit more creative to identify unlinked blobs. Assuming you do not reference blobs from any other places, you can use this **query to fix**:

```
SELECT lo_unlink(l.loid)
FROM   pg_largeobject l
GROUP  BY loid
HAVING (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 t WHERE t.oid = l.loid))
AND    (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 t WHERE t.oid = l.loid));
```

You need to be **superuser** to access `pg_largeobject` directly. Assuming the column name in `table1` and `table2` is `oid`. Simpler query based on [`pg_largeobject_metadata`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-largeobject-metadata.html) in Postgres **9.3 or later** (like [@Daniel commented](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112637/can-i-do-vacuum-full-to-pg-largeobject-table/112646?noredirect=1#comment204992_112646)):

```
SELECT lo_unlink(l.oid)
FROM   pg_largeobject_metadata l
WHERE (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE t.oid = l.oid))
AND   (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE t.oid = l.oid));
```

`pg_largeobject_metadata` is publicly readable. But I don't see the OID of the blob in the system table in versions before pg 9.3 [(incl. pg 9.1)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/catalog-pg-largeobject-metadata.html) - at least not in the manual, I don't have an old version to test right now. So you probably must use my first query.

Compare before and after:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM pg_largeobject;
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_table_size('pg_largeobject'));
```

You might run `VACUUM FULL` now, and test again:

```
VACUUM FULL ANALYZE pg_largeobject;
```

---

You'll be interested in the [additional module **`lo`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/lo.html), that's available for Postgres 9.1. The manual has an accurate description for your problem:

> ... a table entry can reference a large object by OID, but there can be
>   multiple table entries referencing the same large object OID, so **the
>   system doesn't delete the large object just because you change or
>   remove one such entry.**

Bold emphasis mine. The module offers a solution, too:

> The `lo` module allows fixing this by attaching a trigger to tables that
>   contain LO reference columns. The trigger essentially just does a
>   `lo_unlink` whenever you delete or modify a value referencing a large object.

For use cases where each blob is referenced *exactly* once in your whole DB.

---

And obviously also (like [@Daniel mentioned](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112637/can-i-do-vacuum-full-to-pg-largeobject-table/112646?noredirect=1#comment204992_112646)) [**`vacuumlo`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/vacuumlo.html):

> vacuumlo is a simple utility program that will remove any "orphaned"
>   large objects from a PostgreSQL database.

Comment: For querying the mere existence of a large object, in PG 9.0+ we should use `pg_largeobject_metadata` instead of `pg_largeobject`. That's what [vacuumlo](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/vacuumlo.html) does. It's much lighter and is publicly readable.

Comment: @DanielVérité: Good point. However, the manual does not show the blob-oid in `pg_largeobject_metadata` for versions before pg 9.3 - which (oddly!) contradicts instructions on the page for [`pg_largeobject`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-largeobject.html). I added details to the answer. Did you test with pg 9.1?

Comment: The change happened as far back as: Dec 14  2009 in commit  84f910a707: _Use pg_largeobject_metadata.oid instead of pg_largeobject.loid to enumerate existing large objects in pg_dump_ etc...

Comment: About `oid` not being documented. I notice it's the same for `pg_class` so I guess it's a general thing; starting with 9.3 it looks that it was decided that when `oid` is relevant in a system table, it should be explicitly listed. Makes sense.

Comment: That would explain it.

Comment: Sadly AWS RDS is not currently allowing the userland execution of `vacuumlo`. But find [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/174663/48347) my workaround for that disallowance.