# autovacuum daemon considers pg_largeobject table?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, vacuum, autovacuum

I have a table which is having `oid` column and few `oid` column's data might be frequently modified from my application. I thought, it would rewrite the data and replace with new data (basically, thought it will not use additional space). But, its keep on generating new `oid` whenever modification being done. (pg_largeobject table entries increased)

To solve this issue, `lo_manage(oid_column)` trigger created for my table before any update or delete for each row. And it works (like, its removing old oids). `pg_largeobject` entries not increased. but `pg_largeobject` table size keep on increasing.

I read about autovacuum daemon, which will consider if the table is getting any update / delete transactions (`autovacuum_vacuum_threshold` - default 50) or reaches threshold table will be considered for `autovacuum` by the daemon.

I have not enabled this (`autovacuum_vacuum_threshold` is not assigned), so I am assuming its taking `50` by default. And I am sure atleast 200 oids being modified in my table. But I could not see any autovuum logs related to `pg_largeobject` table.

What would be the problem? Is there anyway to solve this problem?

Update 1:

```
mydb=# select * from pg_stat_all_tables where relname='pg_largeobject' and schemaname='pg_catalog';
-[ RECORD 1 ]-----+---------------
relid             | 2613
schemaname        | pg_catalog
relname           | pg_largeobject
seq_scan          | 0
seq_tup_read      | 0
idx_scan          | 38012971
idx_tup_fetch     | 51509025
n_tup_ins         | 11520615
n_tup_upd         | 0
n_tup_del         | 8569404
n_tup_hot_upd     | 0
n_live_tup        | 5453142
n_dead_tup        | 6774593
last_vacuum       |
last_autovacuum   |
last_analyze      |
last_autoanalyze  |
vacuum_count      | 0
autovacuum_count  | 0
analyze_count     | 0
autoanalyze_count | 0
```

Comment: Can you add the result of `select * from pg_stat_all_tables where relname='pg_largeobject' and schemaname='pg_catalog'` to your question, with expanded display (`\x ` in psql, produces one line per column)

Comment: @Daniel, I have updated with statistics.

Comment: Any locking would hold the daemon?

Comment: you still need a VACUUM FULL:
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112637/can-i-do-vacuum-full-to-pg-largeobject-table

Comment: @maletin, I could do. But I can not afford downtime (huge data - might take days)