# Does AWS ever `vacuumlo` PostgreSQL RDS instances?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, blob, vacuum

[Link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/174663/48347) to the long story happened before (and reason to have) this question.

Does AWS ever `vacuumlo` PostgreSQL RDS instances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not, because blindly executing `vacuumlo` on random databases would be foolish.

Unlike `vacuum` that is pretty much unavoidable on a normal live database, `vacuumlo` fixes an oversight, a situation that should not arise in the first place, since applications should unlink the large objects that they no longer use, at about the same time that they delete the references to these large objects.

In a database with a large number of large objects that are properly handled, `vacuumlo` would burn CPU cycles and I/O at each invocation, just to compute every single time that there is nothing to remove.

Moreover, there are two assumptions that `vacuumlo` must do that are debatable:

- the fact that any column of type `oid` should be taken as a candidate to a large object reference. `oid` are used for other purposes, especially if you want to refer to objects in the catalog.
- the fact that, if a large object doesn't have it oid refered in some table **in the same database** , it should be removed. If the reference is in another database, or in a file, or in the same database but embedded in a text column, that logic doesn't work and is in fact dangerous.

Comment: I partly agree. Only partly because not being used (my ignorance) to either of the assumptions you mention. But the agreed part (the application being broken because not unlinking the objects) together with `vacuumlo` being `contrib` make the answer acceptable for me. For the time being.