# How to reduce size of PostgreSQL table after dropping columns?

Tags: postgresql, disk-space, vacuum, size

I have a PostgreSQL database. One table is very large. I want to extract a TEXT column into a separate table and see how much I can reduce the size. The problem is that the size appears to stay the same no matter what I do.

I'm obtaining the size by issuing `\dt+` in psql.

I've tried `VACUUM FULL` and `dp_dumpall` followed by deleting the database and restoring it.

The size of the table did not change.

I added a second TEXT column, watched the size increase by a few hundred MB, deleted the column, and I cannot get the size to go down again.

How can I get the size of the table to go down after deleting these columns?

Comment: `VACUUM FULL` rewrites the table. If there's less data in the table then it would've shrunk. Did you actually `DROP` the column? Are you sure you vacuumed the right column?

Comment: Please show the actual table definition and some sample rows. And *always* your version of Postgres. There might be padding effects to swallow up to 7 additional bytes. Related: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/23933/3684 and  http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/37032/3684

Answer (score 1):

TEXT type columns arent stored with the table data. PostgreSQL treats them like a blob and use a toast table to store the actual data. Maybe thats the reason that you are not seeing the table size shrink.

Comment: When using `\dt+`, the size reported will include size of the TOAST table.