# How to optimize a table for a very high-frequency updates?

Tags: postgresql, update, vacuum

I have a table that contains a list of tasks that need to be run periodically:

```
applaudience=> \d+ maintenance_task
                                                                       Table "public.maintenance_task"
               Column               |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                   Default                    | Storage  | Stats target | Description
------------------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                                 | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('maintenance_task_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              |
 nid                                | citext                   |           | not null |                                              | extended |              |
 execution_interval                 | interval                 |           | not null |                                              | plain    |              |
 last_attempted_at                  | timestamp with time zone |           |          | now()                                        | plain    |              |
 last_maintenance_task_execution_id | integer                  |           |          |                                              | plain    |              |
 disabled_at                        | timestamp with time zone |           |          |                                              | plain    |              |
 maximum_execution_duration         | interval                 |           | not null | '00:05:00'::interval                         | plain    |              |
 maximum_concurrent_execution_count | integer                  |           | not null | 0                                            | plain    |              |
 last_exhausted_at                  | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | now()                                        | plain    |              |
Indexes:
    "maintenance_task_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "maintenance_task_name_idx" UNIQUE, btree (nid)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "maintenance_task_last_maintenance_task_execution_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (last_maintenance_task_execution_id) REFERENCES maintenance_task_execution(id) ON DELETE SET NULL
Referenced by:
    TABLE "maintenance_task_execution" CONSTRAINT "maintenance_task_execution_maintenance_task_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (maintenance_task_id) REFERENCES maintenance_task(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
Options: autovacuum_vacuum_threshold=0, autovacuum_analyze_threshold=0, fillfactor=50
```

Every time a task is selected to be executed, we update the value of `last_attempted_at`. The following query is used to schedule new tasks:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schedule_maintenance_task()
RETURNS table(maintenance_task_id int)
AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY
  EXECUTE $q$
    UPDATE maintenance_task
    SET last_attempted_at = now()
    WHERE
      id = (
        WITH
          active_maintenance_task_execution_count AS (
            SELECT DISTINCT ON (maintenance_task_id)
              maintenance_task_id,
              execution_count
            FROM (
              SELECT
                id maintenance_task_id,
                0 execution_count
              FROM maintenance_task
              UNION
              SELECT
                mte1.maintenance_task_id,
                count(*) execution_count
              FROM maintenance_task_execution mte1
              WHERE
                mte1.ended_at IS NULL
              GROUP BY mte1.maintenance_task_id
            ) AS t
            ORDER BY
              maintenance_task_id,
              execution_count DESC
          )
        SELECT mt1.id
        FROM maintenance_task mt1
        INNER JOIN active_maintenance_task_execution_count amtec1 ON amtec1.maintenance_task_id = mt1.id
        WHERE
          mt1.disabled_at IS NULL AND
          mt1.maximum_concurrent_execution_count >= amtec1.execution_count AND
          (
            mt1.last_attempted_at < now() - mt1.execution_interval OR
            mt1.last_exhausted_at < now() - mt1.execution_interval
          )
        ORDER BY
          mt1.last_attempted_at ASC
        LIMIT 1
        FOR UPDATE OF mt1 SKIP LOCKED
      )
    RETURNING id
  $q$;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
SET work_mem='50MB';
```

`schedule_maintenance_task` query is being run at approximately 600/ minute rate.

The problems start to occur after about 24 hours:

```
applaudience=> EXPLAIN (analyze, buffers)
applaudience-> SELECT id
applaudience-> FROM maintenance_task;
                                                     QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on maintenance_task  (cost=0.00..7715.86 rows=286886 width=4) (actual time=3.675..385.042 rows=31 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=9455
 Planning time: 0.236 ms
 Execution time: 385.060 ms
(4 rows)

applaudience=> SELECT *
applaudience-> FROM pg_stat_all_tables
applaudience-> WHERE schemaname = 'public' AND relname = 'maintenance_task';
  relid   | schemaname |     relname      | seq_scan | seq_tup_read | idx_scan | idx_tup_fetch | n_tup_ins | n_tup_upd | n_tup_del | n_tup_hot_upd | n_live_tup | n_dead_tup | n_mod_since_analyze | last_vacuum |        last_autovacuum        | last_analyze |       last_autoanalyze        | vacuum_count | autovacuum_count | analyze_count | autoanalyze_count
----------+------------+------------------+----------+--------------+----------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+------------+------------+---------------------+-------------+-------------------------------+--------------+-------------------------------+--------------+------------------+---------------+-------------------
 22903432 | public     | maintenance_task |   163230 |      5060130 |  5571795 |       7988441 |         0 |    185359 |         0 |        172989 |     148568 |     138285 |                9733 |             | 2018-12-09 11:00:33.978177+00 |              | 2018-12-09 10:01:07.945327+00 |            0 |             6922 |             0 |              1416
(1 row)
```

The number of dead tuples grows to 100k+. A simple seq scan needs to read 9k+ buffers to fetch 31 rows.

Here is a `VACUUM VERBOSE maintenance_task` log:

```
INFO:  vacuuming "public.maintenance_task"
INFO:  index "maintenance_task_pkey" now contains 9555 row versions in 331 pages
DETAIL:  0 index row versions were removed.
282 index pages have been deleted, 282 are currently reusable.
CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s.
INFO:  index "maintenance_task_name_idx" now contains 9555 row versions in 787 pages
DETAIL:  0 index row versions were removed.
690 index pages have been deleted, 690 are currently reusable.
CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s.
INFO:  "maintenance_task": found 0 removable, 145247 nonremovable row versions in 2459 out of 4847 pages
DETAIL:  145217 dead row versions cannot be removed yet, oldest xmin: 928967630
There were 180 unused item pointers.
Skipped 1 page due to buffer pins, 2387 frozen pages.
0 pages are entirely empty.
CPU: user: 0.05 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.34 s.
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_toast.pg_toast_22903432"
INFO:  index "pg_toast_22903432_index" now contains 0 row versions in 1 pages
DETAIL:  0 index row versions were removed.
0 index pages have been deleted, 0 are currently reusable.
CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s.
INFO:  "pg_toast_22903432": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 out of 0 pages
DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet, oldest xmin: 928967630
There were 0 unused item pointers.
Skipped 0 pages due to buffer pins, 0 frozen pages.
0 pages are entirely empty.
CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s.
VACUUM
```

What can be done to prevent the growing number of the dead tuples/ slowing down of the scheduling query?

Answer (score 4):

The setting [`old_snapshot_threshold`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-OLD-SNAPSHOT-THRESHOLD) was added in Postgres 9.6 for cases like this. A long-open query will not be allowed to hold back the vacuum indefinitely. If the query never needs data that might have been vacuumed away, it will complete as normal. If finds it does need such data, it will throw an error. And if it is part of a forgotten-about connection, it will hang around indefinitely but not cause table bloat while doing so.

Note, however, that this setting prevents `autovacuum` from returning freed space at the end of relations to the operating system, since that is needed to detect the error condition. Only a manual `VACUUM FULL` will still force it. So while it can help to fight one type of table bloat (exactly your problem), it can lead to another kind (often less critical).

Alternatively consider [`idle_in_transaction_session_timeout`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-IDLE-IN-TRANSACTION-SESSION-TIMEOUT), which terminates sessions being idle for too long. Chose your settings wisely.

Comment: I added some additional information. I hope you don't mind. Else I can move it to a separate answer.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, I don't mind, thanks for expanding on it.

Answer (score 2):

My initial assessment was wrong.

Thanks to the help that I have received on Freenode, I was able to understand the underlying cause and solve the ever-bloating table issue.

The first thing I need to correct myself about is the principal understanding of how `VACUUM` works. `VACUUM` cannot reclaim disk space from buffers that are not at end of the on-disk relation file associated with the table. However, `VACUUM` can re-organize buffers at the end of the on-disk relation file associated with the table i.e. if there are many updates and `VACUUM` is being run before new buffers are created, then new rows will be stored in the same buffer in-place of the deleted rows and the number of new buffers is not going to increase.

In order for `VACUUM` to be able to return space to the operating system, the following conditions need to be met:

- one or more pages at the end of a table become entirely free
- an exclusive table lock can be easily obtained
- dead rows are no longer relevant to any of the existing transactions

The fact that my buffers are continuously growing indicates that one of the conditions is not met.

The first thing to check is therefore what are the oldest live transactions:

```
applaudience=> SELECT age(backend_xmin), (now() - xact_start), query
applaudience-> FROM pg_stat_activity
applaudience-> WHERE backend_xmin IS NOT NULL
applaudience-> ORDER BY age(backend_xmin) DESC
applaudience-> LIMIT 1;
   age   |    ?column?     |                                                                                      query
---------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 4644352 | 12:31:38.895198 | -- Metabase                                                                                                                                                                    +
         |                 | SELECT "public"."http_response"."body" AS "body" FROM "public"."http_response" GROUP BY "public"."http_response"."body" ORDER BY "public"."http_response"."body" ASC LIMIT 5000
(1 row)
```

Turns out that in my case there was one *very* long running query preventing VACUUM from deleting dead rows from the buffers. This could be also surmised by looking at the `vacuum verbose` log:

```
DETAIL:  145217 dead row versions cannot be removed yet, oldest xmin: 928967630
```

This entry in the log points in a direction of either extremely high-frequency updates or long-runnig transactions that prevent a clean up.

To solve the problem, I had to:

1. Kill the long running transaction.
2. Run `VACUUM FULL maintenance_task` once.
3. Ensure that there are no long running transactions blocking the VACUUM process.

---

Old answer:

There appears to be no way to update tuples without causing a bloat.

Based on everything I have read, it seems that it will be unavoidable to run a routine `VACUUM FULL` or an equivalent table-rewriting variant.

> Plain `VACUUM` may not be satisfactory when a table contains large
>   numbers of dead row versions as a result of massive update or delete
>   activity. If you have such a table and you need to reclaim the excess
>   disk space it occupies, you will need to use `VACUUM FULL`, or
>   alternatively `CLUSTER` or one of the table-rewriting variants of `ALTER TABLE`.
>   These commands rewrite an entire new copy of the table and
>   build new indexes for it. All these options require exclusive lock.
>   Note that they also temporarily use extra disk space approximately
>   equal to the size of the table, since the old copies of the table and
>   indexes can't be released until the new ones are complete.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html

Assuming I am correct about the above, then the solution is to minimize the impact of the full table-rewrite. To this extent, I have discovered that [`pg_repack`](https://github.com/reorg/pg_repack). `pg_repack` – reorganize tables in PostgreSQL databases with minimal locks.

Since the `maintenance_task` table is small (less than 50 rows), I should be able to run `pg_repack` every hour with minimal impact to the scheduling workers.

Unfortunately, this solution does not work great when a table contains a lot of rows that are being updated regularly.

Comment: "*Ensure that there are no long running transactions*" - for that you could use [idle_in_transaction_session_timeout](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-IDLE-IN-TRANSACTION-SESSION-TIMEOUT)